# CakePHP Can't insert record with foreign key error

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys

I'm getting the following error when trying to insert a record into the table:

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`invoice`.`quotes`, CONSTRAINT `quotes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`contacts_id`) REFERENCES `Contacts` (`id`))

I have a relationship setup between two tables 'contacts' and 'quotes'. 'quotes' has a foreign key set up contacts_id.

The Add method in my quotes controller looks like this:

```
public function add() {
        $this->log('Quote Controller --> Add Method...1');
        $this->log($this->request->data);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {                   
            $this->Quote->create(); // This line writes the details to the database.
            if ($this->Quote->save($this->request->data)) {             
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your quote has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {                
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your quote.');
            }            
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens when you don't have the correct foreign key when trying to save the data.

I am guessing the "contacts_id" value inside $this->request->data is null / empty. You might want to add debug($this->request->data); after $this->Quote->create();

And also it seems that you don't follow the convention of CakePHP. Your contacts_id field should be contact_id. That might help to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Rudy, I'll give this a go this evening, when I get home.

Comment: I was missing a line to populate the foreign key, I have the following but it still isn't working: $this->request->data['Quote']['contact_id'] = '99999999999';

Comment: Are you using 'contact_id' or 'contacts_id' in your table ?

Comment: I changed it 'contact_id' as per your advise.