# Inserting Record into Database with CakePHP Results in Foreign Key Violation

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, foreign-keys

I'm now to CakePHP (a few days) and I'm having issues with inserting records with Foreign Keys.

Basic idea, Warehouses.

I have a *warehouses* table that holds all the available warehouses and I have a *warehouse_types* table to hold the different types of warehouses.  The *warehouse_types* table already has some data in it.

I have a simple add view (based off the blog example in CakePHP's Cookbook) and I have it displaying the names of the different types from the database.

When I save the page I get a Database error.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kvs`.`warehouses`, CONSTRAINT `warehouses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_type_id`) REFERENCES `warehouse_types` (`id`))
```

The SQL that is being generated is:

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `kvs`.`warehouses` (`name`, `location`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('Name Text', 'Location Text', '2014-04-02 12:07:13', '2014-04-02 12:07:13')
```

If I output the information in the request->data object, it shows that it is getting a value for the warehouseType_id.

```
array(
    'Warehouse' => array(
        'name' => 'Name Text',
        'location' => 'Location Text',
        'warehouseType_id' => '1'
    )
)
```

Any help on this would be awesome!

My database tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `warehouses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `warehouse_type_id` (`warehouse_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `warehouses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_type_id`) REFERENCES `warehouse_types` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `warehouse_types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Warehouse extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = 'WarehouseType';
}

class WarehouseType extends AppModel{

}
```

My view (add.ctp) is as follows:

```
<h1>Add Warehouse</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Warehouse');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('location');
echo $this->Form->input('warehouseType_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Create Warehouse');
?>
```

Finally, the add method in my WarehousesController:

```
public function add(){
        //Check Request to see if it is a Post
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Warehouse->create(); //Make a new Warehouse object
            debug($this->request->data);
            if($this->Warehouse->save($this->request->data)){ //Try and save Warehouse
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Warehouse '.$this->request->data['Warehouse']['name'].' created'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); //Redirect back to Warehouse list
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add Warehouse :('));
        }
        $this->set('warehouseTypes', $this->Warehouse->WarehouseType->find('list'));
    }
```

I've read over this answer here that seems the most relevant, but I'm lost: [CakePHP Can't insert record with foreign key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640084/cakephp-cant-insert-record-with-foreign-key-error)

Also reviewed their documentation on saving: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name is different than what is being used in CakePHP. Change CakePHP to use `warehouse_type_id`. (Your CakePHP code is using `warehouseType_id`)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I thought I tried that, but it didn't work!

I've updated the view to use that and it does!

`echo $this->Form->input('warehouse_type_id');`

Answer (score 1):

Change this- on your view file-

## Add Warehouse

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Warehouse');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('location');
echo $this->Form->input('warehouseTypes');
echo $this->Form->end('Create Warehouse');
?>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work.  I get the same error as before.

Comment: if you add `echo $this->Form->input('warehouseTypes');` then how your debug looks like?

Comment: You already accepted a answer? Do you still have that problem?

Comment: The other way seemed to solve it, but I'm curious of your solution as well.  It seems there may be a few ways to do this? My debug output is: 
`array(
 'Warehouse' => array(
  'name' => 'Kevin',
  'location' => 'The Open Road',
  'warehouseTypes' => '1'
 )
)`

Comment: Its all you need your save data with `warehouse_type_id` as the field name. And on view, all depends on you. But try to always stick with Cakephp documentation...

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure how to handle multi-word things in the view.  It seems the view uses _ with lowercase and the controllers use camelCase?

Comment: You can read this part on Cakephp documentation- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements